# How to create a non-nat access point with nmcli?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, wireless-access-point, nat

I am trying to create what is essentially a home router with nmcli. I would like the client devices that connect to be on the same subnet regardless of whether they connect with ethernet or wifi. However when I create my wifi hotspot it creates its own subnet behind a nat. So the devices on the Ethernet are not able to access the devices that are connected via wifi.

The command I am using to create the wifi hotspot is

```
nmcli c add type wifi ifname wlan0 con-name test autoconnect no ssid test -- 802-11-wireless.mode ap ipv4.method shared 802-11-wireless.band bg 802-11-wireless.channel 6 802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt wpa-psk 802-11-wireless-security.psk MyPassword
```

I have tried several things to get this working.

First i tried to switch the ipv4.method to auto, however this forces the connection to never start. Then I tried to create a bridge between Ethernet and the WiFi, however it looks like ap mode does not support bridges in Ubuntu. Everyone, seems to be setting up just a natted access point.

Does anyone have an idea how I can set up an access point that does not create its own nat and subnet?

Comment: On my LAN I set up the wireless router as a switch, basically disabling the router stuff. For admin access, it has a static IP address on my LAN sub-net, but outside of the DHCP pool. Everything wired or wireless on my LAN is all on one sub-net.

Comment: Do you know how to do this using nmcli. That is what I am using to set up the "router"

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to use nmcli (or network manager either), as I am a server person.

Answer (score -1):

Your command is not correct.
Try this

```
nmcli c add type wifi ifname wlan0 con-name test autoconnect no ssid test
nmcli connection modify sentinel 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless.band bg ipv4.method shared
nmcli connection up test
```

Comment: This method creates a new NAT'ed network instead of extending an existing one to WiFi.